# How to insert an unknown number of fields as rows with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form>
<textarea name="text1"></textarea>
<textarea name="text2"></textarea>
<textarea name="text3"></textarea>
</form>
```

However, the number of textareas is determined dynamically so there will not always be just 3.

I want to insert the $_POST of each textarea into a different row with PDO. If they were all going in the same row, I would just use this:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO responses (text1, text2, text3) VALUES (:text1, :text2, :text3)");
$query->bindValue('text1', $_POST['text1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue('text2', $_POST['text2'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue('text3', $_POST['text3'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Although the issue of a changing number of textareas is not addressed by that either.. I was considering using count($_POST) and iterating with a for loop?

How can I go about inserting an unknown number of fields into there own row with PDO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your HTML to send it as an array:

```
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
<textarea name="text[]"></textarea>
```

Then you can just loop over the array `$_POST['text']`

You could probably even do:

```
$params = array_fill(0, count($_POST['text']), '(?)');
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO responses (text) VALUES " . implode(", ", $params));
$query->execute($_POST['text']);
```